# Using BubbleSort to sort numbers into ascending & descending order

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I have created a simple implementation of the bubble sort algorithm. I have tried to make it as efficient as possible by following pseudocode which I have provided below, making some slight modifications to suit my needs.

The pseudocode:

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
    n = length(A)
    repeat
       swapped = false
       for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
          if A[i-1] > A[i] then
             swap(A[i-1], A[i])
             swapped = true
          end if
       end for
       n = n - 1
    until not swapped
end procedure
```

My code:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BubbleSortNumeric {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a set of integers seperated by a space...");
        Integer [] unsortedData = getDataInput();
        Integer [] unsortedData2 = new Integer[unsortedData.length];
        System.arraycopy(unsortedData, 0, unsortedData2, 0, unsortedData.length);
        Integer [] sortedDataAscending;
        Integer [] sortedDataDescending;
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        sortedDataAscending = bubbleSortAscending(unsortedData);
        sortedDataDescending = bubbleSortDescending(unsortedData2);
        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Ascending: " + Arrays.toString(sortedDataAscending));
        System.out.println("Descening: " + Arrays.toString(sortedDataDescending));
        System.out.println("Execution time: " + ((stop - start) / 1e+6) + "ms.");
    }

    private static Integer [] getDataInput() {
        Integer [] userInput = {};
        String strInput;
        try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            strInput = sc.nextLine();
        }
        String [] inputData = strInput.split("\\s+");
        try {
            userInput = Arrays.asList(inputData).stream().map(Integer::valueOf).toArray(Integer[]::new); 
        }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR. Invalid input.\n" + e.getMessage());
        }
       return userInput;
    }

    private static Integer [] bubbleSortAscending(final Integer[] ascendingUnsorted) {
        int n = ascendingUnsorted.length;
        if(n == 1) {
            return ascendingUnsorted;
        }
        boolean swapped;
        int temp;
        do {
            swapped = false;
            for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if(ascendingUnsorted[i - 1] > ascendingUnsorted[i]) {
                    temp = ascendingUnsorted[i - 1];
                    ascendingUnsorted[i - 1] = ascendingUnsorted[i];
                    ascendingUnsorted[i] = temp;
                    swapped = true; 
                }
            }
            n--;
        }while(swapped == true);
        return ascendingUnsorted;
    }

    private static Integer [] bubbleSortDescending(final Integer [] descendingUnsorted) {
        int n = descendingUnsorted.length;
        if(n == 1) {
            return descendingUnsorted;
        }
        boolean swapped;
        int temp;
        do {
            swapped = false;
            for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if(descendingUnsorted[i - 1] < descendingUnsorted[i]) {
                    temp = descendingUnsorted[i];
                    descendingUnsorted[i] = descendingUnsorted[i - 1];
                    descendingUnsorted[i - 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
            n--;
        }while(swapped == true);
        return descendingUnsorted;
    }
}
```

Key things that I've tried to look into, and am currently unsure about:

- Is using arrays the most efficeient way of storing this data to sort etc.?
- Are there ways of making the code shorter, but keeping speed, by using things like `Lambda expressions` like I have done to convert the users input from a `String []` to `Integer []`?
- Overall, is it as efficient as this algorithm can be, or is there further improvements that can be made, without changing the core parts of the algorithm that makes it a bubble sort algorithm?
- I have looked into using generic methods to allow the user to input and sort `char` data, but I was concerned about the effect this would have on performance, given that I'd be handling different data types etc.

Comment: More to the point, why are you trying to optimize bubble sort when there are plenty of better alternate algorithms to implement?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I am studying a decision maths module at school which is all about algorithms, and I thought, as a way to ensure I understand the algorithms, I should make an implementation of them in Java and try and make them as efficient as possible, I know there are better algorithms, but I am currenty studying bubble sort. I will be moving on and implementing better ones as I move on through the module!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Points On Your Existing Code

1. `unsortedData` and `unsortedData2` look weird to me. Try appending a `1` to `unsortedData` to make them line up.
2. `Arrays` has a utility method called [`copyOf(array, length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-) that internally uses `System.arraycopy()`. It will save you a few lines.
3. `sortedAscendingData` or `ascendingSortedData` makes more sense than `sortedDataAscending`. Same for `sortedDataDescending`. This is because `[adjective(s)][noun]` is more natural than `[adjective(s)][noun][more adjectives]`
4. `swapped == true` is redundant. The `while` (or `if`, and so on) construct needs a boolean only. Therefore, you can shorten your `swapped == true` to simply `swapped` and (for example) `swapped == false` to `!swapped`.
5. If you are using `Scanner`, then *stick to it*. `Scanner` is always preferred over `String.split()`.
6. You should declare variables close to where you need them (or in the smallest scope possible). `int temp = array[i];` will do you no harm.
7. Try to keep *typos* (i.e. typographical errors) like *`seperated`* and *`Descening`* to a minimum.
8. If you really want performance, why are you using `Integer`? You should be using `int`. There is a special [`mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) method to deal with `int`s. Carrying around an array of `Integer`s is expensive in terms of memory and computational steps ( due boxing and unboxing).
9. If you really want to use `Integer`, generalise your code by using `Number` instead. You can directly call the `compareTo()` method which is implemented in all classes like [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareTo-java.lang.Long-), [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo-java.lang.Double-), [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo-java.math.BigInteger-), etc. It helps reduce code redundancy, but it *doesn't avoid* the extra boxing/unboxing. This is an example of a readability/performance trade-off.
10. [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is a useful class that helps you compare the `Comparable` implementations in your way. Since you want *performance* I won't discuss it here any further. But it would be better if you take a look at it anyway.
11. One *final* point on `final`: This keyword is used to signify that the concerned variable is now effectively a *constant*, i.e. its value (including its contents) cannot change. Therefore, it makes no sense to add it before the arguments in the sorting methods, as you *are* changing them (internally).

### The Refactored Code

Here is my version of the code, using `int`s and ensures better performance due to absence of overheads. See how I ditched `split()`? I haven't written this from scratch. I just took your code and fixed the parts that needed fixing. I left the others intact.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BubbleSortNumeric {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a set of integers separated by white space.");
        int[] unsortedData1 = getInts();
        int[] unsortedData2 = Arrays.copyOf(unsortedData1, unsortedData1.length);
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int[] sortedAscendingData = bubbleSortAscending(unsortedData1);
        int[] sortedDescendingData = bubbleSortDescending(unsortedData2);
        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Ascending: " + Arrays.toString(sortedAscendingData));
        System.out.println("Descending: " + Arrays.toString(sortedDescendingData));
        System.out.println("Execution time: " + ((stop - start) / 1e+6) + "ms.");
    }

    private static int[] getInts() {
        int[] userInput = {};
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                strings.add(sc.next());
            }
        }
        try {
            userInput = strings
                    .stream()
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                    .toArray();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR. Invalid input.\n" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return userInput;
    }

    private static int[] bubbleSortAscending(int[] array) {
        int n = array.length;
        if (n == 1) {
            return array;
        }
        boolean swapped;
        do {
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if (array[i - 1] > array[i]) {
                    int temp = array[i - 1];
                    array[i - 1] = array[i];
                    array[i] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
            n--;
        } while (swapped);
        return array;
    }

    private static int[] bubbleSortDescending(int[] array) {
        int n = array.length;
        if (n == 1) {
            return array;
        }
        boolean swapped;
        do {
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if (array[i - 1] < array[i]) {
                    int temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i - 1];
                    array[i - 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
            n--;
        } while (swapped);
        return array;
    }
}
```

The reason this version runs faster (verify it) is because it avoids the unnecessary headache of boxing/unboxing. By the way, it was a nice idea to add the pseudocode. I'm looking forward to review more such implementations.

Comment: I have actually just tried running your version of the code against mine, and have found that yours gets stuck after you input a set of numbers, it isn't stuck in a loop, it is just waiting for more input (I think), and doesn't move on...?

Comment: Hmm. I used file redirection. In the console, there is no end of stream per se. Try with some static values or add a  custom functionality that terminates when user inputs 0 or something.

Answer (score 3):

`bubbleSortAscending` and `bubbleSortDescending` are copy-and-paste of the same code except for one character.  That is a very bad idea.  Not only it makes the code longer for no reason, but if you ever want to make a change to one of the functions, you need to remember to change both, or you will get in serious trouble.

You should define just one method `bubbleSort` which takes a second argument which is either an instance of the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, or a lambda that does the same.